# When i create a new app with studio odoo 13. where the views and the main module are generated?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

i create a app with odoo 13 studio but i do not know where are principal  module and the view for developer over this files,
I think it would be created in the following link 
Odoo 13.0e\server\odoo\addons

but i cant find this files, someone to help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M23oJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo studio creates the views/menus/field definitions in the database, rather than a "proper" Odoo module.

You can export your studio customisations as a zip file containing xml data, and re-import into another Odoo instance with studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no files until you export the studio customizations. The export functionality can be found in the studio view at the main menu left upper corner.